Movie with a blonde girl involved in an incestuous relationship with her brother
I watched a movie on cable (most likely on IFC or Sundance, but possibly another paid movie channel) sometime between 2004 and 2006. I watched it, along with "House of Spirits" a few times back to back. Sadly, I can't remember the title or the names of any of the actors. But I do remember the plot quite well:
A young blonde girl has an incestuous relationship with her blonde brother. Shortly after, her parents arrange for her to be married to an older, heavy set man, and he moves her far away to a very grey, icy place. She becomes isolated and depressed. I think she was unable to have children.
When she recieves word that her brother will be visiting, she perks up, obviously still in love with him. But he ends up bringing his new wife, who announces she is pregnant, and it drives the main character over the edge.
In the back-drop, there is an older woman staying in the home as well, who accuses the main character of having a lesbian relationship with her brother's wife, and hints that she knows about her past sexual relationship with her brother. She calls the girl evil or something to that extent.
Anyway, the main character finally kills almost everyone at the end. I am pretty sure the movie begins and ends with the girl on trial in court for murder.
You would think that if I could remember all those details, I would be able to remember the title or the cast!  Can someone help me out please?? Thanks!!!

Some of the points sounf like The House of Yes, while others don't.

Did this movie start off in modern time and then go on to the story inside the main movie?

This plot happens inside The Weight of Water (2000). Also here on youtube. This also happens to be a true story Smuttynose Island.
Woman (blonde/light hair) on small semi depressing island is over joyed at the arrival of her (blonde/light hair) brother. But he arrives with his beautiful wife. There is another woman present who grows suspicious as time goes on of a forbidden incestuous love. Its revealed there was an incestuous love prior to brother and sister marring respective partners. Murder ensues.
The story is told and shown as evidence is pieced together from a group of modern day people looking at the story which is from years past. Liz Hurley and Sean Penn are in modern times and Anders W. Berthelsen plays Evan (brother), Sarah Polley plays Maren (sister) in the scene's of older times.

